# Majority voting in scikit-learn Random forest

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

My main concern is that i need to understand that how does the random forest do majority voting in scikit learn source code. I did not find that specific code in source code of RandomForest. if anybody knows, then kindly explain that. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

To quote from the documentation:

> The predicted class probabilities of an input sample are computed as
>           the mean predicted class probabilities of the trees in the forest. The
>           class probability of a single tree is the fraction of samples of the same
>           class in a leaf.

The predictions are then simply the class with the highest average class probability.

You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/728108383e6655e8f2f86c1c941ff365c7cf937e/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py#L614).

Note that this is different from classical majority voting which is usually understood to be the most common class prediction among trees whereas here the voting happens on the class **probability** level.

The source code for regression is [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/728108383e6655e8f2f86c1c941ff365c7cf937e/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py#L725):

> The predicted regression target of an input sample is computed as the
>           mean predicted regression targets of the trees in the forest.

Comment: +1; to emphasize, sklearn's random forests do not use "majority vote" in the usual sense.

Comment: Agree, and kindly suggest to edit the answer to explicitly point this out

Comment: Done. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

A Random Forest is an ensemble of decision trees. Each decision tree will reach a "conclusion" (i.e., a *prediction*) about each observation. All trees are then combined together.

What does it mean?

- if you are training a Random Forest **regressor**, this combination is an average of each tree's prediction.
- if you are training a Random Forest **classifier**, each tree's classification is combined into a final classification through a "majority vote" mechanism.

Comment: Please notice that what OP asks is "how does the random forest do majority voting in **scikit learn**" (emphasis mine).